# UIWebView transitioning to Youtube video not staying in landscape orientation

Tags: ios

I have an app I'm working on and I have a web view of the youtube channel in landscape but when a video comes up it plays in portrait. How can I force the video to play fullscreen in landscape?

Comment: Having the apps only supported orientations set to landscape can cause this if the devices interface lock is enabled.

Comment: Do you have lots of modal dialogs inside modal dialogs? It can cause wierdness like that.

Comment: Did you find a solution. if so, please post. having the same issue.